# OpenShift installation and Kubernetes dependency

Tags: docker, installation, kubernetes, openshift-origin

Do we need installed and working kubernetes to intall OpenShift or it is right now standalone solution? I don't see any information about it in any of example installation procedure eg:

https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/cluster_up_down.md
or here:
https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/advanced_install.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for an already installed an working Kubernetes cluster when installing OpenShift.  When you install OpenShift using the Advanced Installation guide you already mentioned (and recommended for production environments), you will run an Ansible playbook (part of the [openshift-ansible](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible) project) that will install all the required dependencies (so all required Kubernetes components, specific OpenShift components etc...).

When you just want to play around with OpenShift to see what it is capable of I recommend to check out the [Minishift](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/minishift/getting-started/installing.html) project.  This way you will have an OpenShift environment up-and-running in a matter of minutes.

Comment: I'm asking because i used "oc cluster up" command to set up OpenShift clocally and i do not see any of Kubernetes services. Now im confusing if they are needed? they are not mentioned in any docs. If i want to install OS cluster manually without Ansible, should i install before Kubernetes too or not? Some time ago it was required is it still true? Or maybe it is enough to start master service on master and node service on nodes and thats all?